# Assign a custom binding configuration for wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, wshttpbinding

I'm running into some issues with what I believe is a pretty simple problem.

When trying to send "large" messages over WCF, I am getting the error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quote, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

To remedy this, I created a custom binding configuration with a higher value for MaxReceivedMessageSize. But I still get the error, as if the value is not being read.

Here is my Server App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="largeBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="EMS.Services.TradeController">
       <endpoint address="http://localhost:9002/TradeService"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="largeBinding"
                  contract="EMS.Contracts.Services.ITradeService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And here is my Client App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="largeBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9002/TradeService"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="largeBinding"
            contract="EMS.Contracts.Services.ITradeService"/>
</client>
```

Is there a part I am missing to assign the binding properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the client’s configuration automatically generated by `Adding Service Reference` tool? I suspect whether the client proxy uses the service endpoint created by `Wshttpbinding`. There seems nothing with your current configuration.
Besides, please consider configuring other attributes.

```
     <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="largeBinding" allowCookies="true"
 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
 maxBufferSize="20000000"
 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
 maxArrayLength="200000000"
 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

The `MaxBufferSize` and `ReaderQuotas` property also needs to be configured.
[MaxBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.maxbuffersize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceModel_Channels_HttpTransportBindingElement_MaxBufferSize)
[ReaderQuotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.readerquotas?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.0#System_ServiceModel_BasicHttpBinding_ReaderQuotas)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Your answer was definitely in the right direction.  I had to specify the endpoint explicitly in addition to the binding, and also make sure I wasn't assigning values in the .cs file programmatically, as those take precedence over the .xaml values. Thanks for the help.